# c- TCP client-server Trying to disconnect the clients when I terminate the Server

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

I am using the signal() function to show a message whenever I terminate the server with Ctrl+C. I want to disconnect all clients connected to the server whenever I terminate it but I can't figure it out. Any suggestions?

Comment: When the server exits the clients will automatically be disconnected.